# SwiftUI TabView doesn't not update ui

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection = 0

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            ListCard(isPreferitiSection: false)
                .tabItem {
                    tabSelection == 0 ? Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill") : Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                .tag(0)

            ListCard(isPreferitiSection: true)
                .tabItem {
                    tabSelection == 1 ? Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark.fill") : Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm not getting a handle on why it doesn't change my image within the tab view

Comment: Why are you modifying `tabSelection` using tap gestures? Have you tried following the example in the documentation of [TabView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview)?

Comment: I've seen some examples where they were handled that way, but still even taking that piece out, it doesn't work

Comment: I'm reading that there may be problems with the NavigationView, and in my example ListCard has a navigationView, can that be it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is simple. You are fighting the Human Interface Guides. Apple wants you to use filled symbols for `TabViews`, so, regardless of whether you designate a `.fill` or not, SwiftUI will supply a `.fill`.

You can change this behavior by using the [.environment(.symbolVariants, _:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolvariants)  modifer, but I don't know if you would pass App Review. You would use it like this:

```
    TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
        ListCard(isPreferitiSection: false)
            .tabItem {
                tabSelection == 0 ? Label("Home", systemImage: "house").environment(\.symbolVariants, .fill) : Label("Home", systemImage: "house").environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
            }
            .tag(0)

        ListCard(isPreferitiSection: true)
            .tabItem {
                tabSelection == 1 ? Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark").environment(\.symbolVariants, .fill) : Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark").environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
            }
            .tag(1)
    }
```

You need to use it on both sides of the ternaries, or you will get mismatched type errors.

Lastly, it is much easier to diagnose and debug code if your provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ah thank you, that problem seems to be solved, but what I can't understand is why when I switch between tabs the UI doesn't update

Comment: I thought I was clear about that. The OS, SwiftUI, will automatically replace an unfilled variant for a filled one, without the above. The UI WAS updating, but you didn't see it because ift was simply using the filled variant. However, the selected tab would have colored the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabSelection = 0

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
            ListCard(isPreferitiSection: false)
                .tabItem {
                    tabSelection == 0 ? Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill") : Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
                .tag(0)

            ListCard(isPreferitiSection: true)
                .tabItem {
                    tabSelection == 1 ? Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark.fill") : Label("Preferiti", systemImage: "bookmark")
                }
                .tag(1)
        }
    }
}

struct ListCard: View {
    var isPreferitiSection = false
    init(isPreferitiSection: Bool){
        self.isPreferitiSection = isPreferitiSection
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("isPreferitiSection is \(String(isPreferitiSection))")
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally to me it doesn't work page update when I switch between tabs

Comment: When I copy paste this code, it works for me...